# can anyone tell me how to store geocoder address in android database using android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am able to see the address(for on click listener) fetching from the `GeoCoder` code and i am able to display in log file but i am not able to store that address in my local `DataBase`.

can any one please help me in this issue.

thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.raghotham.androidgeocodelocation;


import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnGPSShowLocation;
Button btnShowAddress;
TextView tvAddress;
final DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(this);

AppLocationService appLocationService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    tvAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(
            MainActivity.this);

    btnGPSShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGPSShowLocation);
    btnGPSShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Location gpsLocation = appLocationService
                    .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (gpsLocation != null) {
                double latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
                String result = "Latitude: " + gpsLocation.getLatitude() +
                        " Longitude: " + gpsLocation.getLongitude();

                tvAddress.setText(result);


            } else {
                showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }
    });

    btnShowAddress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowAddress);
    btnShowAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Location location = appLocationService
                    .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



            if (location != null) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                LocationAddress locationAddress = new LocationAddress();


                locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(latitude, longitude,
                        getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());





            } else {
                showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
    });

}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
         alertDialog.setTitle("SETTINGS");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Enable Location Provider! Go to settings menu?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}

private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {

        String locationAddress;
        switch (message.what) {
            case 1:
                Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                locationAddress = bundle.getString("address");

                Log.d("testing: ", locationAddress);
                break;
            default:
                locationAddress = null;

        }
        tvAddress.setText(locationAddress);
    }
   }
}
```

I am able to store the `latitude and longitude` but not the address part.

Comment: Please reduce the code to a minimum working example. Please take out the extraneous comments, and please apply formatting so its easier to read. (I voted to *Improve*, and not *Close*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply return your address as String and store it in your local db using SQlite. It is easy to store a string in SQLite. Below is the code to get address.

```
 public static String getAddressFromLocation(Context context,
                double latitude, double longitude) {
            String address = "";
            Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> listAddresses;

            try {
                geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                    listAddresses = geocoder
                            .getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    for (Address addrss : listAddresses) {
                        String adminArea = addrss.getAdminArea();
                        Logging(SHOW_LOG, TAG, "adminArea = " + adminArea);

                        String locality = addrss.getLocality();
                        Logging(SHOW_LOG, TAG, "locality = " + locality);

                        String postalCode = addrss.getPostalCode();
                        Logging(SHOW_LOG, TAG, "postalCode = " + postalCode);

                        String address1 = addrss.getAddressLine(0);
                        Logging(SHOW_LOG, TAG, "address1 = " + address1);

                        String cityState = addrss.getAddressLine(1);
                        Logging(SHOW_LOG, TAG, "cityState = " + cityState);

                        String countryName = addrss.getCountryName();
                        Logging(SHOW_LOG, TAG, "countryName = " + countryName);

                    }
                    address = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + " "
                            + listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " "
                            + listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                } else {
                    address = "";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                address = "";
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "address : " + address);
            return address;
        }
```

Comment: Then please accept the answer by clicking on tick icon and up-vote it by clicking on up-arrow icon.